# Getting 404 page not found error while trying to access add new plugin / themes

Tags: plugins, admin, wp-admin, 404-error, admin-menu

I am getting 404 page not found error while trying to add new plugin or view installed plugin in my admin panel. i am using Hueman theme. every time i tried to use some option of admin panel i am getting 404 page not found error.

I tried all basic trouble shooting for this issue.
I would really appreciate if someone help to solve this issue.

this is link on which i am getting 404 page not found error.

1) http://readaddict.com/wp-admin/plugin-install.php

Comment: does the problem goes away if you change theme?

Comment: What happens if you deactivate the theme and activate one of the default themes like twentyfourteen. I have at some stage tested the heuman theme and did not come across any problems

Comment: Yes, @MarkKaplun its not working, even if i change the theme with wordpress default theme i.e twenty fourteen, twenty twelve. still i am facing same issue.

Comment: Your link ask me to login, what kind of 404 do you get?

Comment: @MarkKaplun I am able to login in admin panel but not able to install new plugin (from plugins->add new option) even not able to see already installed plugins (from plugins->Installed plugins option)

Comment: Just a quick though here, is it possible to delete your plugins manually on server side. Seems like a plugin might cause your problem. If you delete a plugin one by one, wordpress will automatically deactivate them.

Comment: yes @PieterGoosen i can delete plugin manually from server. I did this also, I delete all those plugin which may affect htaccess, right now there are few plugin which are as follow
alexa-internet,
recent-posts-widget-extended,
contact-form-7-to-database-extension,
kia-subtitle,
google-analytics-for-wordpress,
vslider,
really-simple-captcha,
meteor-slides,
regenerate-thumbnails,
wp-pagenavi,
light,
contact-form-7
these are those plugin which is there now if you find any plugin which need to be delete please tell or should i delete all plugin. if it won't harm my data.

Comment: You should not loose any data, just the plugin that you will need to reinstall afterwards. It is tough saying which one, but I should say, start with the obvious ones like alexa.... and captchaa and work from there. Remember to delete one by one.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I delete all the plugin one by one but still i am facing same issue. now I am not able to install new plugin because of this issue. Now, What do i do?

Comment: If you deleted all plugins and have a default theme running, then the only thing left is a fresh install of wordpress. I suspect that there are a corrupt file somewhere in the core.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: I got the solution for this, its just about PHP version issue. wordpress or wordpress plugins of wordpress 3.8 does not work with PHP 5.4.

Comment: Go to setting, and change the setting of domain from plain to second last one from bottom, and than try again!